# BackgroundAudioPlayer URL passing from Main Solution to class lib project

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, microsoft-metro

i have few urls and, i want to play them using background player in windows phone 8,

basically, we have 2 project while working with background audio, in windows phone 8

[image]

my problem is :

i have 10 or more online audio urls in to my Main project ( here : sdkBackgroundAudioPlayerCS )

and i want to pass them to MyAudiplaybackAgent.

in

```
 public class AudioPlayer : AudioPlayerAgent
    {
        private static volatile bool _classInitialized;

        // What's the current track?
        static int currentTrackNumber = 0;

        // A playlist made up of AudioTrack items.
        private static List<AudioTrack> _playList = new List<AudioTrack>
        {
                        // A remote URI
            new AudioTrack(new Uri("https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/33803384/stream?client_id=3904229f42df3999df223f6ebf39a8fe", UriKind.Absolute), 
                            "Episode 29", 
                            "Windows Phone Radio", 
                            "Windows Phone Radio Podcast",
                            new Uri("shared/media/Episode29.jpg", UriKind.Relative))
        };
```

here in sample, the url in AudioPlayer.cs , but in my real scenario, i got those url in my project

how to play those url audio via background player.?

**Updated after got answer in post :**

my problem is :

every time, i click on NEXT Button i got new URL for mp3 in main project via webclient method :

and updating the list here

```
 List<SongInfo> list = new List<SongInfo>();
            SongInfo s = new SongInfo();
            s.SongName = some new song name
            s.URL = some new url from webclient
            list.Add(s);
```

and add agian

```
Class1.SaveAudioList(AudioListKey, list);
```

now in BAP project, i want to load that updating list here :

```
// A playlist made up of AudioTrack items.
        private static List<AudioTrack> _playList = new List<AudioTrack>
        {

                        //Class1.LoadAudioList<T>("AudioList", ref list);

        };
```

please give me best solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to communicate with your BAP ([some reference at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202944(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_CommunicationBetweenForegroundApplicationandBackgroundAgent)):

- use a `Tag` property of the *AudioTrack* - but it's very limited and it might be hard to pass a list of songs
- use other resource that main UI and BAP can share - for example *setting* or *file*.

Here is a very basic example of passing a list via *IsolatedStorageSettings*:

```cs
// lets assume that you have a SongInfo class:
public struct SongInfo
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string UriPath { get; set; }
}

// in your main UI you have a list of songs:
List<SongInfo> listOfSongs = new List<SongInfo>();
// we will also need a key to save/read data:
public const string AudioListKey = "AudioList";

// then lets provide two methods Save/Load:
public void SaveAudioList(string AudioListKey, IList<SongInfo> audioList)
{
    IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
    if (settings.Contains(AudioListKey)) settings[AudioListKey] = audioList;
    else settings.Add(AudioListKey, audioList);
}

public void LoadAudioList<T>(string AudioListKey, ref T target) where T : IList<SongInfo>
{
    IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
    if (!settings.Contains(AudioListKey)) throw new NotImplementedException(); // do something - list doesnt exist
    target = (T)settings[AudioListKey];
}
```

Now in main thread you can save your list:

```
SaveAudioList("AudioList", listOfSongs);
```

Loading in BAP should work like this:

```
LoadAudioList("AudioList", ref listOfSongsBAP);
```

Comment: Hi, Romasz, i am on half way ....i updated my question based on your solution. please reply me asap

Comment: @vir My answer shows only example how you can pass some information between BAP <-> UI. Once you save it in UI, then you should reload it in BAP - for example when button is pressed. Of course try to debug your code and see if BAP gets your list.